# Removing and replacing String using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have copied a column data to a file and it looks like-

```
    echo "copy admin.product (components) to 'updateStatement.cql';"
```

O/p file-

```
     ""
     "['1.809859', '1.809859','2.334883']"
     ['3.MYFIT-LTR-DYN']
```

I am trying to remove and replace string using sed but didnt worked

```
     sed -i"s (/[\]\[\"]/,"") "updateStatement.cql
```

Expected o/p-

```
         ''
         '1.809859'
         '1.809859' 
         '2.334883'
         '3.MYFIT-LTR-DYN'
```

Kindly advise

Comment: Can you put the few more lines of the input file?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to do this (GNU awk for multi-char RS):

```
$ awk -v RS='[][", ]+' 'NF' file
'1.809859'
'1.809859'
'2.334883'
'3.MYFIT-LTR-DYN'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
sed -i "s/ *\"/'/g;s/ *[^0-9]*\('[^']*'\)\]*'*/\1/g;s/\(.\)''/\1'\n'/g;" updateStatement.cql
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to replace the `'` and `"`, it is better you write a script, say , sedscript.sed  which contains

```
s/"/'/g
s/,[[:blank:]]?/\n/g
s/\[?\]?//g
s/([[:alnum:]])''$/\1'/
s/.?('[[:alnum:]])/\1/
```

For the input file, **yourfile**

```
""
"['1.809859', '1.809859','2.334883']"
['3.MYFIT-LTR-DYN']
```

Do

```
sed -rf sedscript.sed yourfile
```

which gives :

```
''
'1.809859'
'1.809859'
'2.334883'
'3.MYFIT-LTR-DYN'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you reallu like the line `''` ? When you just want the fields with single quotes, you can use

```
grep -Eo "'[^']*'" updateStatement.cql
```